# toByeArray doesn't exist in my java protobuffer

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am using protoc version 2.5 and the protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar file to compile the following protobuff

```
// This is the type for a publisher looking to sell digital real-estate
message Publisher {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;        // Unique ID number for this person.
  required double ask_price = 3;
  optional string email = 4;

  enum MediaType {
    WEB = 0;
    NEWSPAPER = 1;
    MAGAZINE = 2;
  }

  optional MediaType media = 5;

  enum PhoneType {
    MOBILE = 0;
    HOME = 1;
    WORK = 2;
 }

  message PhoneNumber {
    required string number = 1;
    optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
  }

  repeated PhoneNumber phone = 6;
}
```

I then have the following line in my java code that generates a random Publisher Object by setting the data members on a Publisher.Builder and then calling .build() and returning the result.

```
Publisher pub = genPubProtoBuf();
```

However, pub DOES NOT HAVE the method "toByteArray()". pub is clearly a Publisher which extends Generated Message which extends AbstractMessageLite where toByteArray() is a public method, so Publisher should have it as well. Am I missing something obvious and not correctly building my Publisher Object?

Even stranger, when I look at the .java file that holds the generated code for Publisher, I can't find any mention of toByteArray(), there is only the parseFrom(byte[]) method.

EDIT: The code where I'm calling pub.toByteArray is given below:

```
while (true) {
            Publisher pub = genPubProtoBuf();
            String key = pub.getName() + pub.getEmail() + pub.getMedia().toString() + pub.getPhone(0);
            byte[] byteArr = pub.toByteArray();
            KeyedMessage<String, byte[]> data = new KeyedMessage<String, byte[]>("simple-topic", key, byteArr);
            producer.send(data);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(dataProductionInterval);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not have the method"? Do you mean you tried to call it and there was an error? If so, what was the error? Note that `toByteArray()` is not expected to appear in the generated code because, as you say, it is already inherited from `AbstractMessageLite`. There's no need to declare it again in the subclass.

Comment: See my edit for the actual code I'm calling. I'm using IntelliJ and when I try to compile my class I get a "java: cannot find symbol" error and it points to the toByteArray() call.

Comment: Strange... when I try to compile I also get serveral errors of the form

"java: cannot access com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage, class file for com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage not found"

that's probably my problem, but that really shouldn't be happening unless there's something wrong with my protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar file, am I correct?

Comment: Hmm, it sounds to me like the jar file isn't in the classpath somehow. But I'm not an expert at Java build issues.